# How to connect to github repository using java and github api

Tags: java, github-api, git-remote

I need to create remote Github repository using java (Using my credentials) and I need to push .Json file to that repo.

I saw some examples using JGit and some other references like http://www.codeaffine.com/2015/11/30/jgit-clone-repository/

I've written small code

```
GitHubClient client = new GitHubClient(); 
client.setCredentials("username", "password"); 
RepositoryService service = new RepositoryService(client); 
Repository repo=new Repository(); repo.setName("newRepo"); 
service.createRepository(repo);
```

It isn't working

Please help me with a working example. That would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You will find working examples in [`centic9/jgit-cookbook`](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook), regarding:

- [`Repository repository = createNewRepository();`](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=createNewRepository&type=)
- [`git push`](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/33b0eaaa5ce9538aaf808a0d9aa4c389973b2cf5/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/unfinished/PushToRemoteRepository.java#L72) (which can push any file you have added/commit, JSON or not)